# Regex javascript to only return a value and not full match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

How do we do look behind in java script like we can in java or php?

**RegEx works for php parser using lookbehind**

Here is the working Regex using php parser.

```
 (?<=MakeName=)(.*?)([^\s]+)
```

This produces the value

```
(MakeName=)(.*?)([^\s]+)
```

this produces the match + value

**xml response to extract value from.**

```
<ModelName="Tacoma" MakeName="Tundra" Year="2015">
```

I just need the value

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to apply the regex? Are you using `match` or `exec`? Is the regex global? In particular, when I use your regex and test string with `match` like `"<VechicleDescription...".match(/(xmlns .+?).../)`, I get back an array that includes the value `"Toyota"` as the fifth element.

Comment: No need for a lookbehind both in PHP and JS, use the value inside the corresponding capturing group.

Comment: If your XML is arriving via a request, why not read it using the `responseXML` property on your request? It will have already parsed the content into an XML document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML

Comment: This is inside another software program. Im left with an input field for the Regex. They use javascript to parse it. I cannot use any language. This needs to be done in pure Regex

Comment: if I could use a language I could use groups and be done with it but that's not the case.

Comment: It isn't possible.  You want a magical regex that will simultaneously match and not match at the same time, but without access to the match groups, won't work.

Comment: works in php and java parser. I need it to work in javascript parser

Comment: I think javascript uses (?:) but not sure how to get it to work

Comment: `(?:)` won't work, it's for (non-captured) grouping, but anything matched by it will still end up in group 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is no look-behind in JavaScript.

If you are sure the attribute `MakeName` is present in the input, then you could use this regular expression:

```
/[^"]*(?!.*\sMakeName\s*=)(?="([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/
```

It grabs the first series of characters that do not contain a double quote and have a double quote immediately following it, with an even number of double quotes following after that until the end of the input  (to make sure we are matching *inside* a quoted string), but `MakeName=` should *not* occur anywhere after the match.

This is of course still not bullet proof, as it will fail for some boundary cases, like with single quoted values.:

```
<ModelName="Tacoma" MakeName='Tundra' Year="2015">
```

You could resolve that, if needed, by repeating the same pattern, but then based on single quotes, and combining the two with an OR (`|`).

#### Demo:

```js
var s = '<ModelName="Tacoma" MakeName="Tundra" Year="2015">';

result = s.match(/[^"]*(?!.*\sMakeName\s*=)(?="([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/);

console.log(result[0]);
```